# Plotting hourly time series with unspecified time

Tags: r

I am currently working on a dataframe with 25 columns and 120 rows. As in the dataframe, date and time are stored separately. An extract of my dataframe is like this:

```
          date 1 2 3 4 5 6   7    8    9   10   11   12
1   2013-08-01 0 0 0 0 0 0 369 2416 1934 1125  768  653
2   2013-08-02 0 0 0 0 0 0 401 2328 1962 1080  849  588
5   2013-08-05 0 0 0 0 0 0 551 2855 2317 1099  876  805
6   2013-08-06 0 0 0 0 0 0 420 2382 1937 1065  844  710
7   2013-08-07 0 0 0 0 0 0 405 2397 1930 1081  768  773
8   2013-08-08 0 0 0 0 0 0 391 2273 1942 1098  831  633
11  2013-08-12 0 0 0 0 0 0 555 2938 2163 1071  898  700
12  2013-08-13 0 0 0 0 0 0 323 2375 1819 1087  905  734
```

where only 12 hours out of 24 hours are shown.

I want to have an hourly time series plot with minimal changes to the above dataframe. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a plot with on the x-axis the hour? Say you have x dates, you get x lines? or do you want 1 line combining all dates, say you have x dates, the x-axis will be from 1 to x*24

Comment: I just want one line

Answer (score 1):

You have to melt the `data.frame` to make the hour a single variable, as you want to look at it as a single variable.

```
library(data.table)
hour_cols <- as.character(1:24)
plot_df <-
  melt(your_data_frame, id.vars = "date", measure.vars = hour_cols)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(plot_df, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = date)) +
  geom_point()
```

See `?data.table::melt` for further details on this method.

EDIT: This method will of course will only look good with not too many different dates.  I here considered that there will only be the 12 dates you supplied in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert you date from wide to long format. For this you can use `gather` from `tidyr` (`?tidyr::gather`) and combine date and time:

```
library(tidyr)
long_data <- data %>%
  gather(time, val, `1`:`12`) %>%
  mutate(datetime = paste0(date, " ", time, ":00"))
```

And then plot the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(long_data, aes(x = variable, y = value) +
  geom_point()
```

Comment: If I could arrange my data in a way that there only exists one column for my variable, do you think it would be easier to add date and time on it?

Comment: @FungKwongKit `%>%` is a pipe operator. Here is some information on it: [here](https://spark.rstudio.com/dplyr.html#piping).

Comment: @FungKwongKit I'm not sure I understand the second point. `long_data` have the following columns: `date`, `time`, `val` + `datetime` on the next step. From the nature of `ggplot` you need the format with `x` and `y` as a separate columns.

Comment: I mean if I can put my measured variable in a separate column called `y`, and date together with time in another separate column called `x`, would it be easier for me to add date and time next to the column `y`? as I already had my measured variable in long form